# geonames.org data dump seems incomplete compared to its API?

Tags: api, geocoding

Because of geonames.org's API limit, I tried to download its data dump to match with my record.

However, it seems like the [`allCountries.txt` data dump](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/allCountries.zip) seems incomplete with only ~ 7 million records. Indeed, Geonames.org claims to have over 11 million records.

For example, [Guatemala City -- ID 0003598132](http://api.geonames.org/get?geonameId=0003598132&username=demo&style=full) is available on the API, but not in the `allCountries.txt`.

Am I using the correct data dump? Or is there a more complete dump?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure that Guatemala City ID3598132 is not in your file ?

[image]

I used the version of allCountries.txt found [here](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/).

Comment: You are correct -- it's a failure of my parsing code.